# How to restore topic subscriptions after refreshed token?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I was using gcm tokens to subscribe to specific topics. It was working fine. But now I uninstalled and installed the application again. And the device token is changed.

So Now do I have to subscribe to all topics again? Or are there any solution for that.

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the token is "refreshed" the topic subscriptions are maintained.

If the application is uninstalled, and installed again, then it loose all the data about its past, and you need to re subscribe all the relevant topics.

When an application is uninstalled, it's like the user never installed it.

A new installation is just a fresh new installation.

Comment: Thanx for the explanation

Comment: Can u please tell me why I am getting 400 status code while subscribing to topics via cloud functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553717/400-bad-request-error-while-subscribing-users-to-topic-in-cloud-functio

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate what "refreshed" token means? If it means that token changed, how do we know if we should update? By checking device_uuid (which can change too after reinstall)?