# 400 Bad Request Error while subscribing users to topic in cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to subscribe users to firebase topic on the cloud function. So according to official docs I tried the following code

```
 request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd",
        json: true,


        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Authorization':'key=server key,

        },

        body: JSON.stringify({

          "to": "/topics/name",
          "registration_tokens": ["token value"]

        })
            }, function (error, response, body){
        console.log('error:', error);
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
            console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage);
          }
    });
```

But it's giving 400 status code instead of 200. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparently found different documentation than you did for subscribing a device to a topic.  [This documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_a_relation_mapping_for_an_app_instance) says to use a URL formatted like this:

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME
```

A variation on your code that uses this method is below.  It works for me.  But wouldn't it be much simpler to use [admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions#subscribe_to_a_topic)?

```
 const token = 'f_PWaiHMGvQ:APA91bGN...9F5D5avIpjY57Y098OFsxZLHUZubx0P_';
 const serverKey = 'AAAAyq9marw:APA91b..._Xf-jV472nfn-sb';
 request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/${token}/rel/topics/myTopic`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Content-Length': 0,
            'Authorization':`key=${serverKey}`,
        }
}, function (error, response, body){
    console.log('error:', error);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage);
      }
});
```

Comment: I used that for creating topics. Well I think I can use it to subscribe too. But what about unsubscribing? Btw thanx for answering...

Comment: See my update about using `admin.messaging()`.  It supports both adding and removing subscriptions.

Answer (score 2):

You need proper authorization to use Google API. Have you entered it? (on the headers part of your code). Maybe a clue: if you enter the URL indicated on your code in an address bar of a browser you find this:

`{"error":"MissingAuthorization"}`

As you pointed, error 400 is bad request, i.e., you probably are making some mistake on your requesting action. W3C states:

`The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax`

Maybe this **malformed syntax** it's the absence of this authorization, raising this error 400.

Comment: You haven't added the api key at Authorization: that's why it's giving u authorization error. And here is the doc I'm following https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_a_relation_mapping_for_an_app_instance . Can you tell me where i did wrong

Comment: @Doge , you have to log into Google's Cloud Messaging "control panel" an register yourself as an API user, there you will get a key which you will be using at the `headers` part of your code. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging . I think that's all. Every Google API for us to use demands a registration and only works with it. That occurs with google maps, youtube and so forth. From dog to dog: AU! (means: thank you).

Comment: So just put it on your code, like this `headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':'key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA' ,},` where `AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA` you substitute for your very own key.

Comment: I did. I can't share that key to public. So instead of original key I added "server key" in question