# Firebase Messaging Android SDK - Re-Subscribe to Topics after Token Refresh

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an SDK that uses *FCM Topics*. Whenever the Instance ID `Token` is refreshed, I subscribe again to every topic that user has previously subscribed to (I tested and saw that the *Firebase SDK* doesn't manage the subscriptions updates by itself, please correct me if I'm wrong).

The issue is that if I don't put a `Thread.sleep()` between each call to the Firebase Messaging Instance, the topic subscription fails.

Has anyone tried to do something similar and got different results? To clarify,
 I know about using an end point to register the new token via *Google Instance ID* and not looking to use it for now.
I'm using the `Firebase 11.8.0` SDK.

```
public void refreshTopicsRegistrations() {
    Set<String> registeredTopics = topicsPreferences.getAll().keySet();
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            for (String topic : registeredTopics) {
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(topic);
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic);
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d("topic-refresh", e.getMessage());
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual failure message in its entirety.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore topic subscriptions after refreshed token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553308/how-to-restore-topic-subscriptions-after-refreshed-token)

Comment: @DougStevenson there's no error, simply no push message reaches the app via topics, even after restarting the app. Token still works however

Comment: @AL. unfortunately, no

Comment: Then you're experiencing an unexpected behavior. I suggest reaching out to Firebase support to further debug the issue. Make sure to provide all the details, specially the registration token(s) that is affected.

Comment: Please file a bug report with as many details as possible that helps someone else reproduce the problem. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Will do. Thanks guys for your quick help!